# Cannot upload file to a server

Tags: java

I'm using a function called `UploadFFGS` and this is its content:

```
URL url = new URL("http://linkedme.com/filebet.txt");
        URLConnection ucn = url.openConnection();
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream("filebet.txt"); //before I download the same file because I must edit it and upload the new version
        OutputStream ostream = connection.getOutputStream();
        PrintWriter pwriter = new PrintWriter(ostream);

        pwriter.print(jTextArea1.getText());
        pwriter.close();
```

This program never uploads the file `filebet` I have on my desktop to my link (`http://linkedme.com/filebet.txt`). Any ideas? I call it in this way:

```
         try {

         UploadFFGS();
         } 
          catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(xGrep.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(xGrep.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

Also, NetBeans gives me this error: "java.net.ProtocolException: cannot write to a URLConnection if doOutput=false - call setDoOutput(true)".

Comment: Is there an exception or error of some kind?  When you step through the code in a debugger, at what point does it fail?

Comment: I'm not sure what confusion led to this function. First of all, you cannot simply write to a URL. You need to determine what sort of file upload provisions this site makes -- do you have to POST the file through some form? You also open the connection from the URL no less than three times, and the `FileInputStream` with your source never gets read.

Comment: I posted the errors + exceptions I used

Comment: @TomG The FileInputStream is not used here because I posted only a part of the code (relevant to Upload files). And I am confused too, this is why I asked an help.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach won't work because your API endpoint (most likely) is a regular file rather than an interpreted script. The endpoint must provide a API by means of which you upload a file (POST/PUT etc).

Comment: so should I have to use something else than URLConnection? +1 by the way

Comment: the first step would be to set up the endpoint on linkedme.com. Yes, you can still use it to write the raw contents and save the raw contents of file on the other side.

Comment: set up something like php on the server that will save the whole request body into a file.

Answer (score 0):

I have a different solution. Maybe this will be useful for someone.
Just have a look at your advanced **proxy settings** in your web browser. 
System engineers in our company had changed the **proxy settings** but I was not aware of it.
This error cost me 3 work-days. I got this **doOutput** error while writing a ftp upload project in my company. I tried everything like adding `conn.setDoOutput(true)` or 'fifty shades' of similar solutions but non of them saved me. 
But, **after I changed my proxy settings** to correct ones, the error dissapeared and now I am able to upload my files through ftp using urlConnection in java. 
I used the code in the link below to make an upload process, and did not add anything except host, port, user and password.
http://www.ajaxapp.com/2009/02/21/a-simple-java-ftp-connection-file-download-and-upload/